# How to get data from a Ajax Call to another Ajax Call as separate ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 ajax requests as follows:

**Ajax 1:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var consultdate;
    var timezone;
    var consultstart;
    var consultend;
    $('#consultdate').change(function() {
        consultdate = $('#consultdate').val();
        timezone = '<?php echo $time_zone;?>';
        consultstart = '<?php echo $consultation_start;?>';
        consultend = '<?php echo $consultation_end;?>';
        alert(consultdate);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'qry/timecheck_qry.php',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",
            data: {
                consultdate: consultdate,
                timezone: timezone,
                consultstart: consultstart,
                consultend: consultend
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (!$('#consulttime').data("set")) {
                    //alert(data);
                    $("#consulttime").val('');
                    $('#consulttime').html(data);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error while loading data");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Ajax 2:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    var consultdate;
    var userid;
    var cat;
    $('#consultdate').change(function() {
        consultdate = $('#consultdate').val();
        userid = '<?php echo $user_id;?>';
        cat = '<?php echo $category;?>';
        //alert(consultdate);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'qry/user_date-time_qry.php',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",
            data: {
                consultdate: consultdate,
                userid: userid,
                cat: cat
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (!$('input#consulttime').data("set")) {
                    //alert(data);
                    $("input#consulttime").val('');
                    $('input#consulttime').prop("disabled", false);
                    $('input#consulttime').timepicker('remove').timepicker({
                        'timeFormat': 'h:i A',
                        'disableTextInput': true,
                        'minTime': 'JSON.parse(DATA FROM CALL 1)',
                        'maxTime': '<?php echo $consultation_end; ?>',
                        'step': 15,
                        'disableTimeRanges': JSON.parse(data)
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error while loading data");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am getting output correctly in JSON format:
`"07:25 AM"` for call 1 && `[]` for call 2.

I need to get the data of Ajax call 1 to `'minTime':` `JSON.parse(DATA FROM CALL 1)`, of Ajax call 2.

How is it possible to get the data var from ajax call 1 to ajax call 2  ??

**Update:**

I merged the two calls and resolved it.